# Seagate Backup Plus Slim USB drive freezes Finder copy after a few GB

Tags: macos, hard-drive, freeze

Something weird is going on with my new Seagate Backup Plus Slim 2TB USB drive on OSX. If I start copying a large folder, it goes fine up to about 5-8GB. At that point, the copy operation outright freezes: no more movement no matter how long I wait. The copy also becomes impossible to cancel, and even Disk Utility will show an indefinite spinner while waiting for the drive to show up! Even unplugging the drive doesn't fix this problem: a hard reset is the only way out. This happens regardless of partition format.

I'd have assumed this was a faulty drive, but the behavior is incredibly odd and inconsistent. First, while the copy operation is frozen, I can still copy other files to the drive with no issue. (Unless they're past the 5-8GB limit, in which case they freeze as well.) Second, if I copy files in Windows, through Parallels, there are no freezes at all: the copy goes through to completion. This leads me to believe that this might be some sort of OSX issue, not an issue with the drive itself.

Any thoughts on what this might be?

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible culprit: Duet Display! If I quit Duet Display before the copy, everything works fine. But once I open it, I get the freeze after 5-8GB. How weird.